# Remove Altova Mission Kit

Tags: windows, uninstall

I tried the Altova software, and it's fine, but too much for my humble needs. I uninstalled it. 
Now, every time I right click on anything, the system tries to install Altova Mission Kit 2012. It's crazy, it pops up all the time. 
I can't seem to get rid of Altova. I have uninstalled all Altova products, they do not appear in my add/remove software dialog, so I can't do any further uninstall. I have used Revo uninstaller to try and get rid of them, but it does not find any trace. 
At the same time, my start menu has shortcuts to Altova products (the whole suite). The target for them is greyed out, so I can't edit it. The "start in" reads : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Altova\DiffDog2012\" though there is no folder there. If I click on these shortcuts, I will get the install dialog. Very frustrating and I can't get rid of this thing. How can I completely remove all traces of Altova from my computer?

Answer (score 0):

You did some mistake at time of installation of Altova Mission toolkit.
              They provide the option which functionality you need like(Mapforce,XMLSpy,etc). To remove the specific feature functionality then use same setup which you use at time of installation and disable the feature option on modify option in the altova mission toolkit setup. I never try for removing but I think if you disable all features option then Altova Mission toolkit remove from your system.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem with Altova Mission toolkit 2018. The `eventvwr` tool mentions a problem in `C:\Windows\Installer`.

The solution was to download a fix from Microsoft:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed.